# c++ Changing from second into days,hours.minutes and second

Tags: c++

```cpp
cout << "Please enter the elapsed time in seconds or (0 to end the program): " ;
cin >> totalSeconds;

days = totalSeconds / 86400 % 60;
hours = totalSeconds/ 3600 % 60;
minutes =  totalSeconds/ 60 % 60;
seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
```

The small number works fine but once I start using bigger number it's not working anyone knows why? Here are the logs :

```
Please enter the elapsed time in seconds or (0 to end the program): 62
The equivalent time of 62 seconds in days:hours:minutes:seconds is: :0:0:1:2
Please enter the elapsed time in seconds or (0 to end the program): 9630
The equivalent time of 9630 seconds in days:hours:minutes:seconds is: :0:2:40:30
Please enter the elapsed time in seconds or (0 to end the program): 216000
The equivalent time of 216000 seconds in days:hours:minutes:seconds is: :2:0:0:0
```

both the 62 and 9630 second works fine but not the 216000s

Comment: Show the declaration of those variables and provide a sample `totalSeconds` that you claim is getting computing wrong.  I suspect this is just an integer overflow problem with variable types too small.  But need to see more....

Comment: Is `totalseconds` big enough to contain the number that you enter?

Comment: You need to consider type of the variable here. Please check this link to see the range of values for each integer data types: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: Why `% 60` on your days calculation? Is there only 60 days in a year? Likewise only 60 hours in a day? You really need to pay close attention to these factors.

Comment: Edit your question to add details, don't add them in comments.

Comment: It wont let me copy/paste the variable and declartion @sel

Comment: @Tibo add number of `totalSeconds` in question.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with your formula for days:

```
days = totalSeconds / 86400 % 60;
```

If `totalSeconds` is `5270400` (61 days), that equation will compute `1` for days.  That's probably not your only bug.

Your modulus parameter of `60` on the right of the `%` doesn't appear correct or it's not needed as you are using it.

This is probably what you want without being clever.

```
days = totalSeconds / 86400;
totalSeconds = totalSeconds % 86400;

hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
totalSeconds = totalSeconds % 3600;

minutes = totalSeconds / 60;
totalSeconds = totalSeconds % 60;

seconds = totalSeconds;
```